# Problem creating a VBScript function

Tags: vbscript, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a simple VBScript script, in this I need a function that takes a file path and returns true if there is a file there, and false if there's nothing.

I'm using the following code:

```
Function FileThere (FileName As String) As Boolean
FileThere = (Dir(FileName) > "")
End Function
```

I get the following error:

```
Expected ')'  
800A03EE  
Microsoft VBScript compilation error
```

Any idea what's wrong? I've tested it with just those three lines in the file and the error still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove variable types. BTW, Dir() function  isn't available so you must go with following code:

```
Function FileThere (FileName) 
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FileThere = fso.FileExists(FileName)
    Set fso = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

VBScript only has the variant type, you can't specify types explicitly.

```
Function FileThere(FileName)
    FileThere = (Dir(FileName) > "")
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

1. there are no types as such in vbs
2. Dir function does not exist.

```
Function FileThere(FileName)
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FileThere = fso.FileExists(FileName)
set fso=nothing
End Function
wscript.echo FileThere("c:\boot.ini")
```